# Haskell parser combinator for Haskell identifier

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm writing an anti-quoter in Haskell and I need a Parsec combinator that parses a valid Haskell variable identifier.

Is there one already implemented in the quasiquoting libraries or do I need to write my own?

I'm hoping I don't need to copy/paste the ***ident*** implementation found in http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Quasiquotation.

Comment: I think copying it is probably the easiest way to go.  We really need some support libraries for quasiquotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unlikely that anything in the implementation of Template Haskell itself contains a Parsec parser for anything, because GHC does not use Parsec for parsing--note that it's not in [the list of packages tied to GHC](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Repositories) in various ways.

However, [the module `Text.Parsec.Token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html) gives a means of describing full token parsers for languages, and [the `Text.Parsec.Language` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Language.html) includes some predefined token parsers, including one for Haskell tokens.

Beyond that, you could also look at [the `haskell-src-exts` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts), which is a parser for Haskell source files.